# Is it possible to burn a bootable OSX Mavericks ISO on a DVD?

Tags: macos, mac, iso-image, format

My early 2011 Macbook Pro is almost full right now, and I was thinking about formatting and installing the new OSX Mavericks, because it's free.

But.

Since my Macbook came with OSX Lion 10.7.5 already installed, I don't have any disks, and I'm not quite sure whether my OSX Lion version is "tied" with my Apple ID or with my machine.

The question is: 
How can I be sure that my Apple ID has OSX Lion in it?

If no downloads for OSX Lion are available on my account, can I just download OSX Mavericks and burn it on a DVD and then boot it as new?

Comment: @Ramhound You can also upgrade straight from 10.7 or 10.6 to 10.9. See http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/.

Answer (score 3):

http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/159955/howto-create-bootable-mavericks-iso

I used this and I was able to burn the ISO in Disk Tools and it works...  Takes forever to boot, but now I have a DVD that can install Mavericks....  and an ISO too!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't probably need any bootable installation disk or USB drive.

You can first erase and reinstall 10.7 from the recovery partition. Hold command-R on startup, erase the OS X volume from Disk Utility, and choose Reinstall OS X. See [OS X Lion: Erase and reinstall Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4439). Then upgrade to 10.9 from App Store.

If your Mac came with 10.7, you can reinstall 10.7 from the recovery partition, but you cannot download 10.7 for free from App Store.